# Trace calls sent to a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I made a custom Auto Suggest TextBox. To get data from the view/viewmodel, I made a couple dependency properties. When the view with the control is closed, the control's dependency properties unexpectedly receive null values from an unknown source creating hidden errors. I was able to fix my control to combat any received value but I still can't trace the source of the null values (I verified its not the properties controlling the dependency properties).

How do I trace the source of a call sent to a DependencyProperty ?

---

Update 1

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in AdvanceControl.dll
Set Custom Dictionary Error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Path is null
   at AdvanceControl.AdvanceTextBox.SetCustomDictionary(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\OMEGA\Test\advancecontrol\AdvanceTextBox.cs:line 176
```

This error is invisible unless I try/catch and send it to my output. It does not specify the source of the call to the DP.

Comment: Everything's nulled out on Unloaded event. Your control shouldn't crash because of nulled out DPs.

Comment: I suspected some unload event nulled my DPs. I still would like to Trace calls to my DP for future troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the call stack when it crashes? You'll need to look back a bunch of frames past all the DP frames.

Comment: No errors are visible. I even caught the error via try/catch and wrote it to the Output. The call stack just showed the DP as the source.

Comment: can you post the full call stack?

Comment: What's at line 176? Also, that's only the top frame of the call stack. Where is the rest of it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zh7csxz(v=vs.110).aspx call that one with true.

Comment: Line 176 is where the sample Exception was thrown. Everything else in the output window had nothing to do with error. I tried the Stack Trace. It provided a lot of info but it didn't show the source of event. Maybe there is no direct way to trace a call to the DP.

Comment: Well, post it. It might provide a hint. Also, as the other user commented, if you catched the Unloaded event, that happens before the crash?